# When height increases then why velocity becomes low?

Tags: potential, vectors, velocity, speed, phase-velocity

It's an example.

The satellite is moving around the earth. But when its height increases its velocity becomes low

Answer (score 1):

For the same reason that a ball thrown upward slows down: when gravitational potential energy increases, kinetic energy must decrease, in order to keep the total energy constant.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever something is thrown upwards from a reference level, potential energy increases and the work is done against gravity.So as to conserve energy at each point, kinetic energy decreases and at the highest point ,it certainly drops to zero.Since Kinetic energy is directly propertional to magnitude of velocity,so velocity decreases as well.